# Google maps API gives zero results when Google Maps shows the location

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Im trying to create an autocomplete field sort of like then on that is on top of Google Maps. The Geocoding and Autocomplete API (v3) work very well, except if you try to find a place that's not in the Places library.
For example:
If you search on Google maps for "campus de campolide", it centers the "Universidade Nova de Lisboa" on the map and shows coordinates in the URL. It doesn't show a marker however. I'm guessing that Google maps doesn't have an address for this place and 'predicts' an approximate location. (which may be or not may be correct)

If I try to replicate this in code:

```
if($('#autocomplete').val() !== ""){
  var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
  geocoder.geocode({address: $('#autocomplete').val()}, function(result, status){
    console.log(result);
  });
}
```

I always get ZERO_RESULTS, since obviously it can't retrieve an address. I'm ok with it not finding an address, but I would really like the Geo coordinates that are shown in Google maps in the URL. How can I achieve this using the API?

Comment: You have to accept that Google Maps may have better results/search algorithms than the API's

Comment: The [places API returns that result](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_example_geo2.asp?addr1=campus%20de%20campolide&place=1)

Comment: @geocodezip Indeed, but unfortunately only if you give a location to search nearby and then only within a 50km radius. Google maps seems to do it without any reference location or within an unlimited radius.

Comment: My [linked example](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_example_geo2.asp?addr1=campus%20de%20campolide&place=1) doesn't give it a location to search nearby.

Answer (score -2):

```
var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
geocoder.geocode({ 'address':"your text" }, function(results, status) {
  if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {                     
    console.log(results[0].geometry.location.lat()));                          
  } 
});
```

Comment: Thx, but that's not an answer. If you tried searching for 'campus de campolide' on Google Maps, you would've noticed that Maps actually gives you an approximate position in the URL. I'm asking how to get that kind of response, since geocoder only gives you a location if it finds an address. Your answer just checks whether it gives back an address.